# Scroll Magic Pins used with Anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, scrollmagic

I am having troubles finding a solution for using Anchor Links with Scroll Magic Pins together with Scroll Magic "Section" Pins

Let's Say i have 3 sections on the page. Each on eis the height of the window and gets pined like so:

```
for (var i=0; i<slides.length; i++) {
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: slides[i]
    })
    .triggerHook( 'onLeave')
    .setPin(slides[i], {pushFollowers: false})
}
```

Now I want to use a smooth jQuery Scroll on the Navigation. This works great while scrolling down but gets stuck if i want to scroll back up.
I think it gets lost behind the pinned elements but i can not figure out how to reorder the pins or something like that.

Has anyone a clue how i can get this to work?

Thanks in advance and have a good day :D